# Is it possible to run a game written in Haskell in the browser? (Through GHCJS maybe?)

Tags: haskell, sdl-2, ghcjs, kubernetes-helm

I wonder if it is currently possible to write games in Haskell with [Helm](http://helm-engine.org) or any other engine that run on the browser through GHCJS?

Comment: It would be awesome.

Comment: You should try it and publish your results! I'd be interested to know.

Comment: I might. I guess my first step will be to learn Netwire. If I do something cool, I will share. For now, I think that maybe the WebKit binding could be the way to go.

Comment: @AlexanderVieth I found someone who didn't use WebKit but WebGl. See my own answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found this:
[A game in Haskell with Sodium FRP & GHCJS](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/1qy8sk/online_freecell_game_in_haskellfrpghcjs_with/)

Comment: Still, I plan to write my own little game in Haskell + GHCJS + Netwire. When done, I'll publish the src.

Comment: Very helpful! The blog seems useful.

Answer (score 7):

Here's [Pong](http://elm-lang.org/edit/examples/Intermediate/Pong.elm) in Elm.

And not a full game, but 
  a [turtle swimming](http://elm-lang.org/edit/examples/Intermediate/Turtle.elm)

[Mario walking](http://elm-lang.org/edit/examples/Intermediate/Mario.elm) around and jumping.

Here's a recent ["Brief and Partial Review of Haskell in the Browser"](http://blog.jenkster.com/2015/02/a-brief-and-partial-review-of-haskell-in-the-browser.html)

Comment: But note that Elm is very much *not* Haskell (in my opinion, it is a vastly inferior *language* with a very nice *framework*).

Comment: @Cactus, Elm's compiler is *written* in Haskell, so clearly the Elmers have a more positive view of Haskell than you do of Elm.

Comment: I would agree that Elm is inferior to Haskell, but I would save the phrase 'vastly inferior' for describing JavaScript. :-D